# Вывод информации из списка группами элементов

Tags: python, flask

Как правильно организовать вывод информации?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from getInfoOrGroups import get_person_info

app = Flask(__name__)  # Имя.


@app.route('/')
def index():
    data = get_person_info()
    return render_template('index.html', Info=data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Как в HTML вывести результат этой функции?
Она возвращает список

```
[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]

1 - Имя.
2 - Фамилия
3 - ИД
4 - URL
```

Соответственно таких 1,2,3,4 может быть десятки или сотни.
И надо это вывести так, чтобы информация делилась на эти 4 пункта и заполняла всю страницу.

Comment: В шаблонах можно делать циклы, см. здесь: [Мега-Учебник Flask, Часть 2: Шаблоны](https://habr.com/ru/post/193260/). По вопросу - не понятна связь между списком чисел и именами, фамилиями и т.д. Приведите более адекватный пример. Если в списке имена, фамилии и т.д. - вставьте выдуманные данные вместо чисел.

Comment: Функция get_person_info() парсит из Json данные.
Имя, Фамилию, Ид, URL.
Я их закидываю в список. [Имя, Фамилия, ИД, URL,Имя, Фамилия, ИД, URL]
Т.е Данные на много людей.
И я не знаю, как их правильно передать в функцию Flask'a.
Может и не списком нужно.

И я не смог сделать вставку в HTML с помощью циклов.
Чтобы создавались отдельные Div's для каждого человека.

Comment: Пример с циклом по ссылке в моем комменте смотрели? В шаблоне между `{% for ... %}` и `{% endfor %}` можно вставить один div, он на странице повторится столько раз, сколько итераций в цикле. Данные можно так и передавать как у вас в вопросе показано.

Comment: Cмотрел. Он будет делать Div's вначале с Именем. Потом след. с Фамилией. 
А надо, чтобы залетали данные на одного человека, след. div с другим человеком и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо всем, ответ получен.
Проблема решена.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

К примеру, самый понятный, но не самый питонический вариант:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]

for el in range (0, len(data), 4):
    print (data[el])
    print (data[el+1])
    print (data[el+2])
    print (data[el+3])
```

Можно разбить исходный список на список списков по 4 элемента и потом делать с ними, что хочется:

```
def chunk_by_4(iter):
    for el in range (0, len(iter), 4):
        yield iter[el: el+4]

new_data = list(chunk_by_4(data))

print(new_data)
```

Результат:

> `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]`

Comment: Нужно это всё выводить в HTML и чтобы он заполнял всю страницу.
С этим основная проблема.

И функция может возвращать не только список, но и что-то другое.
Я просто хз, как еще передать много информации во Flask.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего, вам нужно переделать вашу функцию `get_person_info`, чтобы она возвращала не сплошной список, а список словарей с данными каждого пользователя, тогда с данными будет проще работать. В коде ниже у меня эта функция просто возвращает пример данных.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

def get_person_info():
    return [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Василий",
            "surname": "Пупкин",
            "url": "http://sample.com"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Степан",
            "surname": "Иванов",
            "url": "http://sample2.com"
        }
    ]


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    data = get_person_info()
    return render_template('index.html', persons=data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

В шаблоне пишем:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        {% for person in persons %}
        <div>
            <p>Фамилия: {{person.surname}}</p>
            <p>Имя: {{person.name}}</p>
            <p>id: {{person.id}}</p>
            <p><a href="{{person.url}}">Ссылка</a></p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

В результате получается такая страница:

[image: Скриншот]

За основу брал информацию по этой ссылке: [Мега-Учебник Flask, Часть 2: Шаблоны](https://habr.com/ru/post/193260/)

Comment: Функция get_person_info(): дёргает данные с api.
Там может быть и тысяча человек.
Как я для них всех словари сделаю?

Comment: @Джордж, циклом. Если у вас в json данные приходят, то может и не нужно будет ничего переделывать. Но вы исходные данные не показываете, поэтому что-то конкретно нельзя сказать.

Comment: Api вк, метод users.get
Достаю Имя, фамилию, ид и фото.
Если будет много людей, то это надо всё сохранить и перекинуть во Flask.
Да, Json.

Comment: @Джордж, ну значит нет проблем. Если добавите в вопрос пример json, который приходит, то могу показать как его вывести на страницу.