# Как вывести названия блюд списком?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Я занимаюсь созданием сайта для больных диабетом второго типа. Тут будет по идее представлено определенное кол-во разрешенных блюд, их пропорции, белковое содержание и много параметров. Пока что я хочу просто вывести названия блюд списком из своей базы данных непомнюназвания.db на сайт с помощью Python 3.8 Flask.

Проблема в том, что все они выводятся (мало того что довольно криво с кучей скобок и кавычек, но это еще можно пережить) так еще и все вместе кучей.Ниже приведен код из файла routes.py, остальные части кода очень малы и раскиданы по фалам типа manage.py и т.д. по стандарту))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template, request
import sqlite3 as lite


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', result='')


@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def search():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = (request.form['input_query'],)
        con = lite.connect('diacompanion.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("""SELECT name 
                       FROM constant_food 
                       WHERE category = ?""", (query))
        result = cur.fetchall()
        return render_template('index.html', result=result)
```

Comment: прикрепите свой код в виде "кода" ввопросе

Comment: Используйте цикл в шаблоне, например, как в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1057385/1365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде шаблона (у вас это файл `index.html`) нужно подставлять не просто `{{result}}`, а организовать обход списка `result` циклом, например так:

```
{% for row in result %}
<p>{{row[0]}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Такой шаблон после вызова `render_template` преобразуется в html такого вида:

```html
<p>Вареники ленивые отварные</p>
<p>Сырники из творога и картофеля (и т.д.)</p>
...
```

Comment: я попробую, спасибо!

Comment: да, очень круто получилось, и выводит без скобочек, текстом, это ужасно круто))